# How to view iptables rules after deleting the package?

Tags: iptables

If someone has ran `sudo apt remove iptables -y` on a server, is there a way to recover the rules that were being used? I've looked for `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` and `/etc/iptables`, but neither of the directories exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That package contains neither rules nor automation to load rules automatically (e.g. at boot), so whatever you did to set up rules is separate from the package, and probably still there.

We don't know *how* you configured iptables, but that package just contains the iptables executable, not your configuration for it.

Comment: I didn't actually configure them, I'm doing a challenge where I have to upgrade from `iptables` to `nftables` and some other things, but I accidentially uninstalled `iptables` first. Anyways, you answered my question in that they're separate, so thank you!